# Why does MySQL prefers an index range scan using filesort over an index lookup

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, query-optimization

Given is this query, and indexes

```sql
create table entries
(
    id                        bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    parent_entries_id         bigint                                 null,
    group_type                varchar(16)                            not null,
    quantity                  int                                    not null,
    -- a couple of other columns
    created_at                datetime     default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null,
    modified_at               datetime                               null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    constraint FK_396C2CCA677190CC
        foreign key (parent_entries_id) references parent_entries (id)
)
    collate = utf8_unicode_ci;

create index idx_1 on entries (quantity, group_type);
create index idx_2 on entries (group_type, quantity);
```

I want to count all entries with a quantity larger than 0, grouped by their type:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), group_type
FROM entries
WHERE quantity > 0
GROUP BY group_type;
```

I would expect the idx_2 to be used, as it it should provide all data just by an index lookup/iteration, without additional operations, and the explain plans support my thoughts:

```
     type, key_len,      rows, filtered, Extra
idx_1: range,  '4',   667_780,   100, 'Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort'
idx_2: index, '54', 4_218_471, 33.33, 'Using where; Using index'
```

But if I run the query without forcing an index, the database will use the idx_1 (with the temporary table, and the filesort - and yes, it's actually a bit slower), and I don't understand why? Is this my first case a `USE INDEX` clause would be actually helpful?

Comment: Start by updating your index stats (`ANALYZE TABLE entries;`) to make sure they are up-to-date. Then try running an [optimizer trace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_OPT_TRACE.html) to see what cost estimations the optimizer is coming up with for the different options.

Answer (score 2):

If your `WHERE quantity > 0` filter were an equality filter, your first index would accelerate this query really well. It would find the GROUP BY values n the right order to scan the index and generate results without needing any sort. But that's not your situation.

Depending on the exact make and version of your DBMS you might be able to create a function index on `((quantity > 0), group_type)` and thereby get a perfect covering index for your query.

Otherwise you'll need an index scan or table scan and a filesort. filesort is slightly misnamed. It's not a filesystem file, but rather a temporary table-like object that needs to be ordered. If they get really big they spill to disk files, but that's rare.

I suggest you trust the query planner (the part of the DBMS called the "cost-based optimizer" by the folks uptown who use Oracle) rather than forcing the use of an index. As long as you do `ANALYZE TABLE entries` after bulk loads, the query planner will do a credible and future-resilient job of deciding whether it's faster to use an index or simply scan the table.